# Elementary OS Desktop multitask view through terminal

Tags: pantheon-terminal, desktop, pantheon

I'm new on elementary OS and I'm looking for a way to launch the multitask view of desktop through a terminal command

My goal is to use "Gesture" app and to asign a command to a gesture to show the multitask view

[image: elementary multitask view]

[image: Gestures app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger this through dbus: `dbus-send --session --dest=org.pantheon.gala --print-reply /org/pantheon/gala org.pantheon.gala.PerformAction int32:1`. This is how the .desktop file opens the multitasking view (https://github.com/elementary/gala/blob/master/data/gala-multitaskingview.desktop.in).

Comment: Many thanks for your help and your link ! It's working !

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a command from terminal without extra packages, but if you install **xdotool** you can run terminal commands to emulate keyboard shortcuts. You can install it by `sudo apt install xdotool` and if you didn't change the default keyboard shortcut for Multytask View you can launch it from terminal (or a custom script) by `xdotool key super+s`. Using xdotool you can assign to a gesture any keyboard shortcut you have or define using System Preferences for example.

sources: https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/
https://neal.codes/blog/adding-mac-like-touch-gestures-to-elementary-os